# Jade Pug each iteration changed by Select box choice

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I have just started using a Pug/Jade template to iterate through an object of events I have send from an express app. It works great but now I have added a select box with a drop down (select) populated by the venues in the event object. My problem seems simple but I'm not really sure if it is possible and how to go about doing it. Basically, I want to change the select item then have the events for that particular venue only shown. The list of events starts off with all venues but I want to change the select box then only show the events for that venue. Here is a bit of my code.

app.js

newEventList & venueList arrays sent to the route and rendered by index.pug

index.pug(event list)

```
ul#grid
  each event in newEventList
    li
      div.event
        h4.eventTitle= event.name
        h6.eventDesc= event.venue
        h6.eventStart= event.startTime
```

index.pug(venue select box)

```
  .styled-select#VenueSelect
      select
        each venue in VenueList
          option(value=(venue.name)) #{venue.name}
```

Can I filter the events within the pug code or would I need to do the filtering in the app.js file and resend it back to the template? Any advice greatly received. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have the right intuition: There needs to be some dynamic code, on the frontend and the backend. You have a couple of options, but all of them involve some asynchronous communication (e.g. an AJAX call or a page redirect). I'm going to list what I think are the two most straight-forward ones below:

1) You could have a venue select event trigger a call to a server endpoint. This call could pass along the selected venue, and the endpoint could then return a list of events that take place in that venue. Once the frontend (the client) receives the response from this call, some frontend code would need to render that list into the browser. This code would be executed in the browser, so without Pug as a templating framework. jQuery is an option for these kind of DOM manipulations, but MVC frameworks can make this task easier (if you have the time to spare to learn them).

2) You could have a venue select event trigger a redirect to a page with a parameter attached (e.g. `/index.html?venue=xyz`). This parameter could be accessed from `app.js` on the server and passed to the Pug template. The Pug template  could then render the new page appropriately. This approach is a bit more old-fashioned than 1), but should also work.

Comment: Thank you, this does help. I was hoping to not have to reload the whole page when it changes so I think a framework would be a good way to go. I'm going to see which one would be the easiest to use for this purpose. Thanks